# JQuery XML have .text() return only current node text

Tags: jquery, xml

Sorry for the vague title.  Here's an example of what I'd like to do.

```
<book>
  The Lord of the Rings
  <author>JRR Tolkien</author>
</book>

$xml.find("book").each(function()
{
  $(this).text();
});
```

$(this).text(); returns not only "The Lord of the Rings" but also  ... and any other nodes inside .  I'm looking for a consistant way to return only "The Lord of the Rings" or whatever information i have in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely that text will always preceed tag so you can grab first node of contents also

```
$(xml).find('book').each(function(){
   var text=$(this).contents().eq(0).text();
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nS5bj/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `contents()` to get all nodes and then `.filter()` it to get rid of any nodes that are not text nodes:

```
$xml.find("book").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).each(function() {
    // $(this).text();
});
```

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298758/298479)</sup>

If the code needs to work in IE7, too, you'll have to replace `Node.TEXT_NODE` with `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the element and remove that clone's children, leaving the bare text:

```
$xml.find("book").each(function()
{
    var title = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
});
```

The use of [`.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) here is key, as it terminates the `.remove` operation (removing all child tags), leaving the leftover text.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD8LH/)